# Rust: BTreeMap equality+inequality range query

Tags: pagination, rust, range, b-tree

I want to call `range` on a BTreeMap, where the keys are tuples like `(a,b)`. Say we have:

- `(1, 2) => "a"`
- `(1, 3) => "b"`
- `(1, 4) => "c"`
- `(2, 1) => "d"`
- `(2, 2) => "e"`
- `(2, 3) => "f"`

The particularity is that I want all the entries that have a specific value for the first field, but a range on the second field, i.e. I want all entries where `a = 1 AND 1 < b <= 4`. The `RangeBounds` operator in that case is not too complicated, it would be `(Excluded((1, 1)), Included((1, 4)))`. If I have an unbounded range, say `a = 1 AND b > 3`, we would have the following `RangeBounds`: `(Excluded((1, 3)), Included((1, i64::max_value())))`.

The problem arises when the type inside of the tuple does not have a maximum value, for instance a string (`CStr` specifically). Is there a way to solve that problem? It would be useful to be able to use `Unbounded` inside of the tuple, but I don't think it's right. The less interesting solution would be to have multiple layers of datastructures (for instance a hashmap for the first field, where keys map to... a BTreeMap). Any thoughts?

Comment: You can usually use the `..` family of operators to avoid writing `Excluded` and `Included`. I find this easier to read. For example, `(Excluded((1, 1)), Included((1, 4)))` could be replaced with `(1, 1)..=(1, 4)` which returns an object of type `RangeInclusive<(i32, i32)>`.

Comment: I want to make queries like "find all tuples with first value = x" or "find all with last value = y". However, for the last value, the range isn't exactly working. `range((1, 3)..=(3, 3))` also finds `(2, 1)` because it falls between `(1, 3)` and `(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first field of your tuple is an integer type, then you can use an exclusive bound on the next integer value, paired with an empty `CStr`. (I'm assuming that `<&CStr>::default()` is the "smallest" value in `&CStr`'s total order.)

```
let range = my_btree_map.range((Excluded((1, some_cstr)), Excluded((2, <&CStr>::default()))));
```

If the first field is of a type for which it is difficult or impossible to obtain the "next greater value", then a combination of `range` and `take_while` will give the correct results, though with a little overhead.

```
let range = my_btree_map
    .range((Excluded((1, some_cstr)), Unbounded))
    .take_while(|&((i, _), _)| *i == 1);
```